# Title only if foreach exists

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have the following code:

```
foreach ($model->details as $detail) {
  if ($detail->Title) echo $detail->Title;
  if ($detail->Info) echo '<br />'.$detail->Info;
}
```

Now I want to add something like this:

```
'<h2>Details</h2>'.'<hr />'
```

to the top of the output but only when the if's in the foreach clause are met.  If neither of the if's is met I want nothing to display at all.

Can some help me tweak my code to accomplish this?

Comment: What if only 1 of them is met? What do you want to happen then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to output to a string, or use the [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php). The following example uses the string approach:

```
$sOutputHtml = NULL;

foreach ($model->details as $detail) {
  if ($detail->Title) $sOutputHtml .= $detail->Title;
  if ($detail->Info) $sOutputHtml .= '<br />'.$detail->Info;
}

if ($sOutputHtml !== NULL) {
  echo '<h2>Details</h2>'.'<hr />' . $sOutputHtml;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like so?

```
foreach ($model->details as $detail) {
    if ($detail->Title && $detail->Info) {
         echo '<h2>Details</h2><hr />';
    }
    if ($detail->Title) echo $detail->Title;
    if ($detail->Info) echo '<br />'.$detail->Info;
}
```

---

Addendum: I'd probably rather do something like this, to also avoid the uneccessary `<br />` when there's no Title, but only Info

```
foreach ($model->details as $detail) {
    $text = array();
    if ($detail->Title) $text[] = $detail->Title;
    if ($detail->Info)  $text[] = $detail->Info;
    if (!empty($text)) {
        echo '<h2>Details</h2><hr />';
        echo implode('<br />', $text);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your approach but it still printed the header over each item of the array instead of only once on top and the array displaying below.  Thanks for providing input.

Comment: @enfield: Ah, my mistake. I misunderstood your question. However, you can still use the array+implode method to avoid the unnecessary `<br />`. Just combine Shi's solution with mine